# Is this an 'only if' sentence, or a 'if' sentence?

Tags: logic

The sentence is:
Bertha eats only regularly if Anna does.

The only abbreviations are:
A: Anna eats regularly
B: Bertha eats regularly

Is this an 'only if' sentence or a 'if, then' sentence.
Is it symolized (if):
A -> B

or (only if):
'not A' -> 'not B'
alternatively: B -> A

Why I ask is because I get the impression that she maybe would have normally eaten a lot, but if Anna eats regularly, then she also does it.
Any thoughts?

Comment: The sentence can be rewritten "if Anna eats only regularly then Bertha eats only regularly."

Comment: I forgot to add something about the abbreviations. Do you still think I can do it?

Comment: I'm not even sure the original sentence is grammatical English. The best answer might be: no, it's neither.

Comment: @Henning: It’s at best pretty tortured English. I suppose that it can be given sense by interpreting *eats only regularly* as *always eats according on a regular schedule from which she never deviates*, but it does require a bit of imagination to get there, and I don’t think much of the exercise.

Comment: I agree with the other comments.  I don't think your abbreviations are appropriate; rather I would treat "only regularly" as a combined adjective having no effect other than to modify the verb "eats," in which case there are still two possible interpretations:  "If Anna eats, then Bertha eats only regularly" and "If Anna eats only regularly, then Bertha eats only regularly."  Consider the modified "Bertha eats slowly if Anna does."

Comment: Thank you! I also am starting to think that it is neither of them. I also think that it can't be symbolized since B doesn't mean 'Bertha eats only regularly'? Or is it the same? English isn't my nativ lanugage, so I may understand incorrectly. Is there any significant difference between 'regularly' and 'only regularly'?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your comment before now. So I was wrong in thinking it can't be symbolized. 
I am leaning towards saying it is an 'if' situation: "If Anna eats only regularly, then Bertha eats only regularly."

Comment: I would definitely say that is B->A